# JS cookie bar would not repeat on the refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies

Got this cookie bar:

HTML:

```
<div id="cookie-bar-bottom" class="cookie-bar">text...
<a href="index-cookies.html" class="cookie-policy">
   <b><text style="color: rgb(230,0,100)">Cookies</text></b>
</a>
<input id="cookie-hide" class="cookie-hide" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none'" value="Agree" type="button">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cookie-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    background: rgb(0,140,250,1);
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 100;
    transition: .8s;
    animation: slideIn .8s;
}
```

I would need better solution probably via JS to prevent cookie bar popping up on next refresh. Ideally so browser cache would remember this cookie has already been agreed to and so will never show up again in that browser.

Anyone helping me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only thing missing (the JS functionality):

```
<script>
function closeCookieNotice() {
    const nowDate = new Date();
    const expireDate = new Date(nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() + 30)).toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "cookie_notice=0;path=/;expires=" + expireDate + ";";
    document.getElementById("cookie-bar-bottom").style.display = "none";
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const cookie_notice = ('; ' + document.cookie).split('; cookie_notice=').pop().split(';')[0];
    if (cookie_notice !== "0") {
        document.getElementById("cookie-bar-bottom").style.display = "block";
    }
});
</script>
```

**Explained:** it sets cookie on bar close and check if the cookie is set on page load. If the cookie is set then the bar is not showing. Simple, lightweight and will does it job.